# Why is a borrow still held in the else block of an if let?

Tags: rust

Why does the call `self.f2()` in the following code trip the borrow checker? Isn't the else block in a different scope? This is quite a  conundrum!

```
use std::str::Chars;

struct A;

impl A {
    fn f2(&mut self) {}

    fn f1(&mut self) -> Option<Chars> {
        None
    }

    fn f3(&mut self) {
        if let Some(x) = self.f1() {

        } else {
            self.f2()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=233df12995163bd046c1102cbc6e7e23&version=stable)

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
13 |         if let Some(x) = self.f1() {
   |                          ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |             self.f2()
   |             ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
17 |         }
   |         - first borrow ends here
```

Doesn't the scope of the borrow for self begin and end with the `self.f1()` call? Once the call from `f1()` has returned `f1()` is not using self anymore hence the borrow checker should not have any problem with the second borrow. Note the following code fails too...

```
// ...
if let Some(x) = self.f1() {
    self.f2()
}
// ...
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ea17e84ea5fb55c9aed6aa62b17cdaf4&version=stable)

I think the second borrow should be fine here since `f1` and `f3` are not using `self` at the same time as `f2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's annoying, but you can work around this by introducing an inner scope and changing the control flow a bit:

```
fn f3(&mut self) {
    {
        if let Some(x) = self.f1() {
            // ...
            return;
        }
    }
    self.f2()
}
```

As pointed out in the comments, this works without the extra braces.  This is because an `if` or `if...let` expression has an implicit scope, and the borrow lasts for this scope:

```
fn f3(&mut self) {
    if let Some(x) = self.f1() {
        // ...
        return;
    }

    self.f2()
}
```

Here's a log of an IRC chat between Sandeep Datta and mbrubeck:

> **mbrubeck:** std:tr::Chars contains a borrowed reference to the string that created it. The full type name is `Chars<'a>`. So `f1(&mut self) -> Option<Chars>` without elision is `f1(&'a mut self) -> Option<Chars<'a>>` which means that `self` remains borrowed as long as
>   the return value from `f1` is in scope.
>
> **Sandeep Datta:** Can I use 'b for self and 'a for Chars to avoid this problem?
>
> **mbrubeck:** Not if you are actually returning an iterator over something from `self`. Though if you can make a function from `&self -> Chars` (instead of `&mut self -> Chars`) that would fix the issue.

Comment: This works even if you remove the braces around the `if let` expression.

Comment: Answer accepted because you also gave a work around in addition to an explanation.

Comment: However I think the follow up question has not been answered fully. "self remains borrowed as long as the return value from f1 is in scope." sounds like an artifact of the way the borrow checker works now. There are several different lifetimes conflated with each other here the `self.f1` borrow does not have the same lifetime as the `self.f3` borrow still they are represented by the same lifetime `'a`.

Answer (score 12):

I put together an example to show off the scoping rules here:

```
struct Foo {
    a: i32,
}

impl Drop for Foo {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Foo: {}", self.a);
    }
}

fn generate_temporary(a: i32) -> Option<Foo> {
    if a != 0 { Some(Foo { a: a }) } else { None }
}

fn main() {
    {
        println!("-- 0");
        if let Some(foo) = generate_temporary(0) {
            println!("Some Foo {}", foo.a);
        } else {
            println!("None");
        }
        println!("-- 1");
    }
    {
        println!("-- 0");
        if let Some(foo) = generate_temporary(1) {
            println!("Some Foo {}", foo.a);
        } else {
            println!("None");
        }
        println!("-- 1");
    }
    {
        println!("-- 0");
        if let Some(Foo { a: 1 }) = generate_temporary(1) {
            println!("Some Foo {}", 1);
        } else {
            println!("None");
        }
        println!("-- 1");
    }
    {
        println!("-- 0");
        if let Some(Foo { a: 2 }) = generate_temporary(1) {
            println!("Some Foo {}", 1);
        } else {
            println!("None");
        }
        println!("-- 1");
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
-- 0
None
-- 1
-- 0
Some Foo 1
Foo: 1
-- 1
-- 0
Some Foo 1
Foo: 1
-- 1
-- 0
None
Foo: 1
-- 1
```

In short, it seems that the expression in the `if` clause lives through both the `if` block and the `else` block.

On the one hand it is not surprising since it is indeed required to live longer than the `if` block, but on the other hand it does indeed prevent useful patterns.

If you prefer a visual explanation:

```
if let pattern = foo() {
    if-block
} else {
    else-block
}
```

desugars into:

```
{
    let x = foo();
    match x {
    pattern => { if-block }
    _ => { else-block }
    }
}
```

while you would prefer that it desugars into:

```
bool bypass = true;
{
    let x = foo();
    match x {
    pattern => { if-block }
    _ => { bypass = false; }
    }
}
if not bypass {
    else-block
}
```

You are not the first one being tripped by this, so this may be addressed at some point, despite changing the meaning of some code (guards, in particular).

Answer (score 4):

As of Rust 2018, available in Rust 1.31, the [original code will work as-is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a09e7ce2bac27db09b8c215fac82e2f). This is because Rust 2018 enables [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423).

Answer (score 3):

A mutable reference is a *very* strong guarantee: that there's only one pointer to a particular memory location. Since you've already had one `&mut` borrow, you can't also have a second. That would introduce a data race in a multithreaded context, and iterator invalidation and other similar issues in a single-threaded context.

Right now, borrows are based on lexical scope, and so the first borrow lasts until the end of the function, period. Eventually, we hope to relax this restriction, but it will take some work.

Comment: I guess that a mere availability of two mutable references to the same data would *not* introduce a data race just by itself :) at the very least, you need two threads to get a data race.

Comment: it may not be a data race, but still has problems, like iterator invalidation

Comment: Yes, sure. I only argued against the "data race" term specifically.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can get rid of the spurious errors. I am new to Rust so there may be serious errors in the following explanation.

```
use std::str::Chars;

struct A<'a> {
    chars: Chars<'a>,
}
```

The `'a` here is a lifetime parameter (just like template parameters in C++). Types can be parameterised by lifetimes in Rust.

The `Chars` type also takes a lifetime parameter. What this implies is that the `Chars` type probably has a member element which needs a lifetime parameter. Lifetime parameters only make sense on references (since lifetime here actually means "lifetime of a borrow").

We know that `Chars` needs to keep a reference to the string from which it was created, `'a` will probably be used to denote the source string's lifetime.

Here we simply supply `'a` as the lifetime parameter to `Chars` telling the Rust compiler that the lifetime of `Chars` is the same as the lifetime of the struct `A`. IMO "lifetime 'a of type A" should be read as "lifetime 'a of the references contained in the struct A".

I think the struct implementation can be parameterised independently from the struct itself hence we need to repeat the parameters with the `impl` keyword. Here we bind the name 'a to the lifetime of the struct A.

```
impl<'a> A<'a> {
```

The name `'b` is introduced in the context of the function `f2`. Here it is used to bind with the lifetime of the reference `&mut self`.

```
fn f2<'b>(&'b mut self) {}
```

The name `'b` is introduced in the context of the function `f1`.This `'b` does not have a direct relationship with the `'b` introduced by `f2` above.

Here it is used to bind with the lifetime of the reference `&mut self`. Needless to say this reference also does not have any relationship with the `&mut self` in the previous function, this is a new independent borrow of `self`.

Had we not used explicit lifetime annotation here Rust would have used its lifetime elision rules to arrive at the following function signature...

```
//fn f1<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Chars<'a>>
```

As you can see this binds the lifetime of the reference `&mut self` parameter to the lifetime of the `Chars` object being returned from this function (this `Chars` object need not be the same as `self.chars`) this is absurd since the returned `Chars` will outlive the `&mut self` reference. Hence we need to separate the two lifetimes as follows...

```
fn f1<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Option<Chars<'a>> {
    self.chars.next();
```

Remember `&mut self` is a borrow of `self` and anything referred to by `&mut self` is also a borrow. Hence we cannot return `Some(self.chars)` here. `self.chars` is not ours to give (Error: cannot move out of borrowed content.).

We need to create a clone of `self.chars` so that it can be given out.

```
Some(self.chars.clone())
```

Note here the returned `Chars` has the same lifetime as the struct A.

And now here is `f3` unchanged and without compilation errors!

```
fn f3<'b>(&'b mut self)  {
    if let Some(x) = self.f1() { //This is ok now

    } else {
        self.f2() //This is also ok now
    }
}
```

The main function just for completeness...

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = A { chars:"abc".chars() };

    a.f3();

    for c in a.chars {
        print!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

I have updated the code the make the lifetime relationships clearer.