# Is there a way to release a binding before it goes out of scope?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to parse a file using regexes:

```
extern crate regex; // 1.0.1

use regex::Regex;

fn example(
    section_header_pattern: Regex,
    section_name: &str,
    mut line: String,
    mut is_in_right_section: bool,
) {
    loop {
        if let Some(m) = section_header_pattern
            .captures(&line)
            .and_then(|c| c.get(1))
        {
            is_in_right_section = m.as_str().eq(section_name);
            line.clear();
            continue;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

...but the compiler complains because the `RegEx`'s `captures()` method has a borrow which endures for the lifetime of the match:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `line` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
13 |             .captures(&line)
   |                        ---- immutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |             line.clear();
   |             ^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
18 |             continue;
19 |         }
   |         - immutable borrow ends here
```

By the time I get to `line.clear();`, I'm done with the `Match` and would like to clear the buffer and move onto the next line in the file without further processing. Is there a good/clean/elegant/idiomatic solution or do I need to just bite the bullet and introduce a subsequent 'if' block?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30243606/155423 ?

Comment: Unrelated to your question; why do you use `.eq(`? I've seen other people do the same. What's the rationale behind avoiding `==`?

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure if they're duplicates since the other question is dealing with the else block (which I don't have) and is solved by an early return.

Comment: @Shepmaster For my part, and probably true for others as well, experience with Java has made us bit gunshy about using == for string comparison. In Java, the == operator compares the memory offset/pointer of the strings instead of a deep comparison of bytes/characters .

Comment: I was afraid it was Java. It's so strange that a high level language like Java made such a mis-step with `==` while Rust, a much lower level language, favors value equality over reference equality.

Comment: @Shepmaster Java didn't misstep at all. Value equality can be expensive and doesn't always mean what you think it might, particularly when inheritance gets involved. Explicit value-comparators are often better. Java also built on C which uses reference equality for the `==` operator.  Many languages do.

Comment: @par this probably isn't the best venue to argue about it, but that sounds more like "inheritance makes code hard to understand"; I'm not sure how an `equals` method is exempt from any inheritance strangeness that would affect `==`. Expensive operations that do the *correct thing* will always beat out fast operations that don't do what the programmer wants. We have also learned that you cannot just point to C as the gold standard. If that were the case, Java would not exist, much less Rust! It's tricky to say C has reference equality, as it has *value equality of pointers*, which is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: No.

> I'm done with the `Match`

You may be, but the compiler doesn't know that. Specifically, lifetimes are currently bound to the lexical scope they are defined in. The feature you are looking for is called [*non-lexical lifetimes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423). It's not stable now, but it's planned to be enabled in the Rust 2018 edition.

As an example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let matched = &s[..];
    println!("{}", matched);

    s.clear();

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

A programmer can tell we are done with `matched` after we print it, but the compiler says that the borrow lasts until the closing `}`. The fix is to introduce a scope:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    {
        let matched = &s[..];
        println!("{}", matched);
    }
    s.clear();

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Your case is more insidious, as the decision to clear the string is interwoven with the value of the borrow of the string itself. Something like this would be my first place to reach:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let do_clear;

    {
        let matched = &s[..];
        println!("{}", matched);
        do_clear = matched.contains("ll");
    }

    if do_clear {
        s.clear();
    }

    println!("{}", s);
}
```

However, your specific case might be able to be transformed to avoid multiple `if` / `if let` statements:

```
let is_in_right_section = section_header_pattern.captures(&line)
    .and_then(|c| c.get(1))
    .map_or(false, |m| m.as_str() == section_name);

if is_in_right_section {
    line.clear();
    continue;
}
```

Which wouldn't look too bad if you introduce a new type and/or method. As a bonus, there's a place for the `Regex` to live:

```
struct Section(Regex);

impl Section {
    fn is(&self, s: &str, section: &str) -> bool {
        self.0
            .captures(s)
            .and_then(|c| c.get(1))
            .map_or(false, |m| m.as_str() == section)
    }
}

// ----

if section.is(&line, section_name) {
    line.clear();
    continue;
}
```

---

The original code works as-is when NLL is enabled:

```
#![feature(nll)]

extern crate regex; // 1.0.1

use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let section_header_pattern = Regex::new(".").unwrap();
    let section_name = "";
    let mut line = String::new();
    let mut is_in_right_section = false;

    loop {
        if let Some(m) = section_header_pattern
            .captures(&line)
            .and_then(|c| c.get(1))
        {
            is_in_right_section = m.as_str().eq(section_name);
            line.clear();
            continue;
        }

        return; // I don't really want to loop
    }
}
```