# Non-lexical lifetime workaround failure

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

`get()` returns a reference to a vector item, pushing the value beforehand if necessary:

```
struct Container {
    vec: Vec<i32>,
}
impl Container {
    fn find(&mut self, v: i32) -> Option<&mut i32> {
        None // we don't care the implementation
    }

    fn get(&mut self, v: i32) -> &mut i32 {
        match self.find(v) {
            Some(x) => x,
            None => {
                self.vec.push(v);
                self.vec.last_mut().unwrap()
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container { vec: Vec::new() };
    let x = container.get(42);
}
```

It does not compile because `self` is still borrowed when we try to push the value (`self.vec.push(v)`):

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.vec` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> test.rs:13:17
   |
10 |         match self.find(v) {
   |               ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
13 |                 self.vec.push(v);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
17 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

This is due to [non-lexical lifetime](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2016/04/27/non-lexical-lifetimes-introduction/#problem-case-2-conditional-control-flow).

So as a workaround, I thought I could rewrite `get()` to limit the scope of `self.find()`:

```
fn get(&mut self, v: i32) -> &mut i32 {
    if let Some(x) = self.find(v) {
        return x;
    }
    self.vec.push(v);
    self.vec.last_mut().unwrap()
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.vec` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> test.rs:13:9
   |
10 |         if let Some(x) = self.find(v) {
   |                          ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
13 |         self.vec.push(v);
   |         ^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
14 |         self.vec.last_mut().unwrap()
15 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

I can't understand why.

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/30243606/155423

Comment: The problem is very similar, but different in that my if-block returns the unwrapped value (as `&mut i32`), so the accepted workaround in the other post (which is in fact similar to my failing sample) does not apply here.

Comment: @rom1v, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/2731452

Comment: Thank you for this link, which perfectly answers my question.